# Windows 10 Search - Multiple shortcuts with different command line arguments

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I want to open a program with command line arguments via shortcut by typing into the start menu to search for it, and pressing `<Enter>` on it. (Since it's a folder, I don't want to create a program specific .sln file for it as a workaround)

In my specific case, it's for Visual Studio 2019 and opening a path to a folder, so the shortcut target should be **`<devenv.exe> <MyFolder>`**.

I put this shortcut into the Start Menu folder, and to my surprise it doesn't show up when I type the name into the search bar! However, when I remove the existing "Visual Studio 2019" shortcut from the Start Menu folder and then try typing it in again, it shows up like I expect it to. At this point it functions well.

However I'd like to keep both shortcuts on the start menu. Is there some way I can get the Windows 10 search to show both shortcuts? I have tried using a .bat file, and that works perfectly fine but was wondering if there is a "non-workaroundy" way.